# Basil Starts Wilting After I Cut the Branches

Tags: basil

I grow my basil outdoor and it grows well ... until yesterday. But two days ago I cut some branches of basil plant and the next day it starts wilting. I thought the air temperature is too high (about 30 degrees Celcius) and the humidity is about 50-60% so I spray the leaves to increase the humidity. The electrical conductivity is about 1 mS/cm (500 ppm) and the pH is 5.8 - 5.9. What should I do to make it stop wilting

Comment: PPM is high, and pH is low. It doesn't happen to me. A picture would be helpful. You mean the whole plant is wilting?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes I mean the whole plant is wilting, the leaves still in green but wilting. Then the colour of leaves and stem turns brown. I am very sorry, the plant dead two days after I posted this question and I didn't take any picture of it. Next time if this happen again I will update this post.
Thank you for responding my question.